# Encountering type error handling when running allennlp test-install

Tags: huggingface-transformers, allennlp

I am using Windows 10 and pip installed the latest allennlp branch. When I successfully install the package, I encountered the following:

```
$ allennlp test-install

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\604194\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\Scripts\allennlp.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\allennlp\run.py", line 15, in <module>
    from allennlp.commands import main  # pylint: disable=wrong-import-position
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\allennlp\commands\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from allennlp.commands.configure import Configure
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\allennlp\commands\configure.py", line 27, in <module>
    from allennlp.service.config_explorer import make_app
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\allennlp\service\config_explorer.py", line 24, in <module>
    from allennlp.common.configuration import configure, choices
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\allennlp\common\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from allennlp.common.from_params import FromParams
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\allennlp\common\from_params.py", line 48, in <module>
    from allennlp.common.params import Params
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\allennlp\common\params.py", line 173, in <module>
    class Params(MutableMapping):
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\allennlp\common\params.py", line 236, in Params
    def pop(self, key: str, default: Any = DEFAULT) -> Any:
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\overrides\overrides.py", line 67, in overrides
    return _overrides(method, check_signature, check_at_runtime)
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\overrides\overrides.py", line 93, in _overrides
    _validate_method(method, super_class, check_signature)
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\overrides\overrides.py", line 114, in _validate_method
    ensure_signature_is_compatible(super_method, method, is_static)
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\overrides\signature.py", line 87, in ensure_signature_is_compatible
    super_sig, sub_sig, super_type_hints, sub_type_hints, is_static, method_name
  File "c:\users\604194\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\domains\lib\site-packages\overrides\signature.py", line 213, in ensure_all_positional_args_defined_in_sub
    f"`{method_name}: {sub_param.name} must be a supertype of `{super_param.annotation}` but is `{sub_param.annotation}`"
TypeError: `Params.pop: key must be a supertype of `<class 'inspect._empty'>` but is `<class 'str'>`
```

Any advice on how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

EDIT: Edited my question for more information if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Windows environment, but I am unable to reproduce this bug. Are you running the latest version of Python?

Comment: @arjuns I'm currently running Python 3.7.10 and I would ideally like to keep this fixed. Should I look for an older release of allennlp to install on my computer? If so, do you know what the latest repo that supports Python 3.7.10? Thanks!

Comment: Python 3.7.10 should be fine. If you don't mind, could you uninstall allennlp and please follow the steps [here](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp#installing-via-pip) exactly. Please let us know if you run into issues still; sorry, it's difficult for us to say more right now without the ability to reproduce this issue.

Comment: We don't currently officially support AllenNLP on Windows, so we're leaving it up to the community to supply an answer if there is one. Thanks for your question!